# Insert a <span> tag with content in an empty <div> tag in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The original HTML:

```
<div class = "a">
  <div class="firstNumber">
     <span class="spanClass">4</span>
  </div>

  <div class="secondNumber"> </div>
</div>

<div class = "b">
     ..."firstNumber" div tag repeats here...
     ..."secondNumber" div tag repeats here too but might contain content...

</div>
```

I used following code to check if "secondNumber" div tag is empty.
If it is, then I want to add "0" wrapped with a span tag with the same "spanClass" name
inside the "secondNumber" div tag. But it's not working...

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        if ($.trim($('.secondNumber').text()).length==0){
             $(".secondNumber").wrapInner("<span class="spanClass">0</span>"); 

        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You should take a look at your string here: "<span class="spanClass">0</span>". That isn't a valid string. Try using: '<span class="spanClass">0</span>' and firebug under firefox or even developer tools at chrome so it helps you with the visible errors on your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('.secondNumber').each(function(i, el) {

   if($(this).find('.spanClass').length == 0) {

        $(this).html('<span class="spanClass">0</span>');

   }

});
```

**Edit**

```
$(function() {
    $('.secondNumber').each(function(i, el) {

       if($(this).find('.spanClass').length == 0) {

            $(this).html('<span class="spanClass">0</span>');

       }

    });
});
```

Comment: it worked on jsfiddle but not on my site. It must be a problem somewhere else. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Why use wrapInner when you know the contents are empty? Why not:

```
$(".secondNumber").html('<span class="spanClass">0</span>');
```

EDIT:

Also, It looks like your problem really isn't the wrapInner (although I still think .html() is better), but rather your quoting getting in the way. Look at my example. I have single quotes on the outside. You have two sets of double quotes which will be in contention with each other if you don't escape the inner set of quotes.

Comment: Yes, telling OP to look into the console should display a syntax error due to the bad quoting.

Comment: I have played with your code as well as @andres descalzo's (his has the opposite quotes around the span tag, it worked on jsFiddle, but it didn't work on my real site. It leads me to believe that the problem is somewhere else. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: It doesn't look like the result of trim().length=0 on the empty div tag, as I used "!=0" and the html() changed other span tags.But I couldn't figure out what else it could be other than 0. do you guys think I am looking at the right spot for problem?

Comment: Have you tried replacing .length=0 with checking the content instead: $.trim($('.secondNumber').text()) = ''

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your code, you should use single quote for the class attribute.

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $second = $('.secondNumber'); // caching the object
    if ( $.trim($second.text()).length == 0 ){
        $second.wrapInner("<span class='spanClass'>0</span>"); // or $second.append("...")
                              //  -----^
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MKE4T/

Comment: Your code worked in jsfiddle, but I don't know why it didn't work on my real site. I believe the problem is somewhere else. Thanks for your effort.