# Replace empty value in <div> tag with 0 and wrap it with <span> tag + class name in jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert a <span> tag with content in an empty <div> tag in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572661/insert-a-span-tag-with-content-in-an-empty-div-tag-in-jquery)

I posted the same question earlier today with 4 answers all seem to be working in jsFiddle but not on my real site. I want to address the issue in a different way so someone might be able to help me out here as I couldn't figure out what was wrong with my code.

Here is the original HTML which I have no control over:

```
<div class="a">
   <span class="b">4</span>
</div>
```

In the original code, whenever there is no value between the span tags, the entire span line is gone. It leaves the code like this:

```
<div class="a"> </div>
```

I want to achieve the following result to have the span line appear also even there is no value.

```
<div class="a">
   <span class="b">0</span>
</div>
```

It seems to me there is a white space between the div tags, so I used a trim method. The 4 answers I got were very similar to mine but nothing worked on my real site. Could it be something else I didn't figure out?

This is what I have tried:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {

        if ($.trim($('.a').text()).length==0){
            $(".a").html('<span class="b">0</span>');


        };
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library and did you translate the pseudo-named classes correctly?

Comment: `I posted the same question earlier today`. You can update your original question to add clarifications if you feel users who answered are not understanding your issue. Otherwise you possibly asking a duplicate question.

Comment: Sorry I thought I couldn't fill that many lines in the comment box in the original post. I am going back to the original one now... Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

        if ($('.a').children('span').length == 0){
            $(".a").html('<span class="b">&nbsp;</span>');
        };
});
```

It's a small variation from your code to check if `.a` has a children `span` tag and also I fill the tag with an empty space as I think that would be in more consonance with the original code.

Also take care if you have more tha one `div` with `class=a` then you have to adapt the above `if` statement within an `.each` loop to iterate every element.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use children.length in this case if you have nested elements

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        if ($('.a').children().length == 0){
            $(".a").html('<span class="b">0</span>');
        };
});
```

But this will only work if you have elements Inside.. if you are looking to check for the just  text of div this approach will not work..